# Display JSON string array in VUE

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a JSON data that I'm fetching and I'm having problems display an array in front.

So currently I'm getting this output:

```
Id: 1
name: Adam
Factors: ["One","Two"]
```

I want it to be displayed like this:

```
Id: 1
name: Adam
Factors: One Two
```

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
 "credits": [
{  
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Adam",
 "Factors" : ["One", "Two", "Three"]
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "name": "Jonas",
 "Factors" : ["One", "Two", "Three"]
}
 ]
}
```

And this is my front code in VUE:

fetching data:

```
 export default {
name: 'app',
data(){
  return{
    isOpen: false,
    id: '',
    credits: []
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.search()
},
 methods: {
  search() {
    if(this.id!="") {
      axios
              .get(`http://localhost:5041/credits/`, {
                params: {

                  ...this.id && {id: this.id}
                }
              })
              .then(response => {

                this.credits = response.data

              })
    }
  }
```

And my div where info is displayed:

```
<div v-show="isOpen">
  <p>Credit ID: {{credits.id}}</p>
  <p>Client: {{credits.name}}</p>
<p>DE Factors: <li>{{credits.Factors}}</li></p>
</div>
```

So, how do I access all of the array elements of the exact post?
This is what I'm getting on display:
Factors: ["One","Two"]
This is what I want to display:
Factors : One Two

Comment: You can use v-for to iterate over array elements

Comment: `credits.Factors.join().replace(',', ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop :

```
<div v-show="isOpen">
  <p>Credit ID: {{credits.id}}</p>
  <p>Client: {{credits.name}}</p>
<p>DE Factors: <li> <span v-for="Factor in credits.Factors" :key="Factor"> {{ Factor }} </span> </li></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
<div v-show="isOpen">
  <p>Credit ID: {{ credits.id }}</p>
  <p>Client: {{ credits.name }}</p>
<p>DE Factors: {{ credits.Factors.join(' ') }}</p>
</div>
```